# Getting inline css in an ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I have an ASP.NET MVC website running in the windows azure cloud.  It includes links in the  section like this one:

```
<link href="Content/Case02.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Sometimes the css is delivered within the page (inline) and sometimes it is not.  I want to set something so that it is always delivered to the browser as a seperate GET.

The website is www.caselines.co.uk

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I am understanding your question here. If you want the CSS to be displayed "inline", like I assume you're saying, then you can just use a `<style>` code block.

```
<style type="text/css">
       ...
</style>
```

The way that you are linking the stylesheet in your question is an external stylesheet, so I don't quite understand what you mean by "sometimes the CSS is delivered inline".